# Saving Image files in server after response

Tags: c#, asp.net

My asp.net application saving a long list of image files and then
have to view one of them.
The client can browse the images,
But its take a long time.
I have a dictionary with key - file path and value -Image:

```
Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image> imageList = new Dictionary<string,System.Drawing.Image>(); 

//filling imageList 
foreach (KeyValuePair<imagePath, System.Drawing.Image> item in imageList)
{
    item.Value.Save(item.Key, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

I am looking for some way to save just one image file,
make response, and continue saving the other image files,
there is any way to do it?
maybe with Thread?
Thanks!

Comment: which one time-consuming browsing or saving, can u explain more detail?

Comment: The saving takes a long time

Comment: when u are saving a image, on the other hand simultaneously, you trying to browse, right?

Comment: No, just the first image displayed, 
After complete response,the client can browse through photos
But until then saving ends

Answer (score 0):

Disk IO may be very slow, nevertheless you can try this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, System.Drawing.Image> item in imageList)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        lock (item.Value)
            item.Value.Save(item.Key, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the images saving in thread block and it works perfectly and fast:

```
Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image> imageList = new Dictionary<string,System.Drawing.Image>(); 

//filling imageList

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, System.Drawing.Image> image in imageList)
    {
       image.Value.Save(item.Key, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
});
thread.Start();
```